# Developping Android app for deprecated version (gingerbread) on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have to develop an app for a device on gingerbread version (9-10) of Android.
Android studio don't allow to have a minSDK less than version 14.

Is there a solution to develop and build an app for gingerbread version ?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you just need to install an old enough SDK via the Android Studio SDK Manager first(?)

Comment: How does Android Studio not allow it? You just can't use the support or androidx libraries, which have a minSdk of 14 and are added by default to a new project. Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: we i try to create a new project, the minSDK i can choose is 14. i had already downloaded the SDK for gingerbread.

Comment: There's also [an archive of old Android Studio versions](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) but I don't remember if it used to support older SDKs. Maybe(?)

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Studio 2.3.3 (the oldest version). You'll find API-9 the minimum SDK.